# How to manage more users in a telegram bot?

Tags: python, variables, bots, telegram, telepot

I did a telegram bot with python, who send a message like

```
if message == '/start':
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Insert your name:")
    a = 'name'
if a == 'name' and message != '/start'
    name_user = message
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Insert your birthday:")
    a = 'birth'
    and so on for other information...
```

the problem came when at the same time two users use my bot because the first user change 'a' so the second start with the birth and not with the name, can someone help me please?

Comment: Consider *tying* the `a` variable to request sessions.

Comment: How i can do this @MosesKoledoye ?

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267473/how-can-make-conversation-between-bot-and-user-with-telepot)
It would fit to your question as well, but I'm not sure this is a duplicate, because your question is better - but I also don't want to copy-paste my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store with user ID.

```
a[chat_id] = name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a database for that purpose. have a field called `State` with a primary field of user's ChatID.
after each response from your users check the state of that user from db.

Sean's answer is also correct but this way you will lose your users states if your program restarts for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should to consider a database, create it using sqlite3. Into the database create a table which corrisponds to each user (eg. table: db(str(chat.id))). And into each table create columns where you could put the information of your users (including also chat.id).