# How can make conversation between bot and user with telepot

Tags: python, telepot

I want to create the bot with `telepot` that ask the users frequent questions.
For example first ask 'whats your name.?' then the user reply 'user-name',then ask how old are you? and the user reply his age and ...

I had written a code for this chat between user and bot,but sometimes I am getting error. Please guide me how can I make this bot with `telepot`.?

I want to make conversation between bot and users with `telepot`

Answer (score 2):

> I am no longer maintaining this library. Thanks for considering
>   telepot.
>   <sub>- the maintainer, nickoala</sub>

---

What you're looking for is `DelegatorBot`.
Consider [this tutorial](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#id14).

> Consider this scenario. A bot wants to have an intelligent
>   conversation with a lot of users, and if we could only use a single
>   line of execution to handle messages (like what we have done so far),
>   we would have to maintain some state variables about each conversation
>   outside the message-handling function(s). On receiving each message,
>   we first have to check whether the user already has a conversation
>   started, and if so, what we have been talking about. To avoid such
>   mundaneness, we need a structured way to maintain “threads” of
>   conversation.

DelegatorBot provides you with one instance of your bot for every user, so you don't have to think about what happens when multiple users talk to it. (If it helps you, feel free to have a look at [how I am using it](https://github.com/lucidBrot/shiverBot/blob/master/shiverbot.py).)
The tutorial's example is a simple counter of how many messages the user has sent:

```
import sys
import time
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from telepot.delegate import pave_event_space, per_chat_id, create_open

class MessageCounter(telepot.helper.ChatHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageCounter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._count = 0

    def on_chat_message(self, msg):
        self._count += 1
        self.sender.sendMessage(self._count)

TOKEN = sys.argv[1]  # get token from command-line

bot = telepot.DelegatorBot(TOKEN, [
    pave_event_space()(
        per_chat_id(), create_open, MessageCounter, timeout=10),
])
MessageLoop(bot).run_as_thread()

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

This code creates an instance of `MessageCounter` for every individual user.

> I had written a code for this chat between user and bot,but sometimes I am getting error.

If your question was rather about the errors you're getting than about how to keep a conversation with state, you need to provide more information about what errors you're getting, and when those appear.

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli What do you mean by that? (Perhaps you should ask a new question, if it is something new you're asking about. Feel free to ping me with the question link in a comment here)

Comment: thankyou so much, I figure out how to resolve this problem, but now I have another problem, I've asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194664/problem-tharead-if-i-use-telepot-and-telethon-toghether Thankyou :)

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli I'm afraid, I haven't worked with telethon yet. I don't know the answer to that question of yours. Good luck!

Comment: can i use delegator bot only for a part of the bot? like only for a function or things like this?

Comment: @LeonardoScotti I don't know, it's been a while since I've touched that. But you should probably use a different library altogether, given that this one is no longer maintained and no longer adapted to telegram API changes.