# How to store user data and display them according to their corresponding callbacks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot, datastore

**Here's my code:**

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
import telegram, telegram.ext

u = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True)
j=u.job_queue

def set(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_says=' '.join(context.args)
    user_says=user_says.split(' ')
    global item, chat_id
    item=user_says[1:]
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    j.run_once(callback, int(user_says[0]))

def callback(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'Great you won {item}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp = u.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('set', set))
    u.start_polling()
    u.idle()
```

So the problem is if someone start the timer and in the mean time when the timer is running someone else (or the same person) start different timer the value of item get replaced with the newest one, it will display wrong item value for all the timers which are already running in that time (except for the latest one) how can I store items and show them with their corresponding timer's callback

*Hope you understood my question :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use a dict to store the items and the chat_id with an UUID as a key, then, pass the UUID to the callback function and retrieve the items from the dict.

```
from uuid import uuid4
items = {}

def set(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    user_says=' '.join(context.args)
    user_says=user_says.split(' ')
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    uid = uuid4()
    items[uid] = {"id": chat_id, "item": user_says[1:]}
    j.run_once(callback, int(user_says[0]), context=uid)

def callback(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    uid = context.job.context
    chat_id = items[uid]["id"]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f'Great you won {items[uid]["item"]}')
    del items[uid]
```

Read more about multi-users handling in [How to manage more users in a telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46099662/9478891)

Comment: but what if user starts another timer with different item?

Comment: Then, you might want to use an UUID as key instead of chat_id

Comment: can you please guide me? I am a beginner :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO [Knugis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328604/10606962) is unnecessarily complicated. Instead of storing some data in a global dict and then passing the key to `context`, you might as well just pass the data directly, e.g. as tuple:

```
j.run_once(callback, int(user_says[0]), context=(chat_id, user_says[1:]))
```

and then

```
def callback(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    uid, user_says = context.job.context
    ...
```

On a somewhat related note I'd like to point out that PTB already comes with a built-in mechanism to store user/chat-related data. See [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot,-user-and-chat-related-data) for details.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.